# Problems with FFMPEG concat and/or MP4BOX

Tags: video, ffmpeg, mp4, h.264, mp4box

I've been searching for a reliable way to concat a large (>30) number of mp4 files.

My methods so far have been trying the MP4BOX concat CLI, and FFMPEG's concat filter (such as `ffmpeg -auto_convert 1 -y -f concat -i files.txt -c copy out.mp4`).

Both tools produce the same problem: joining 2 or 3 files seems to work great, but any greater number produces a corrupted mp4 file (such as https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_mWxBuwYcSgQjQtUnpQeUxVTm8/view). I can create a workaround where I join only 2 videos at a time, until all videos have been joined, but this does not work for an odd number of joins (i.e. 13).

Why do these methods work on some files, but not others?

FFPROBE produces errors as you would expect on these corrupted files:

```
error while decoding MB x y, bytestream z
Reference 2 >= 2
top block unavailable for requested intra mode
```

example FFMPEG output:

```
ffmpeg version N-80901-gfebc862 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.8 (Ubuntu 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.3)
  configuration: --extra-libs=-ldl --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --mandir=/usr/share/man --enable-avresample --disable-debug --enable-nonfree --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --disable-decoder=amrnb --disable-decoder=amrwb --enable-libpulse --enable-libfreetype --enable-gnutls --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libvorbis --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-libvpx --enable-libspeex --enable-libass --enable-avisynth --enable-libsoxr --enable-libxvid --enable-libvidstab
  libavutil      55. 28.100 / 55. 28.100
  libavcodec     57. 48.101 / 57. 48.101
  libavformat    57. 41.100 / 57. 41.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.102 / 57.  0.102
  libavfilter     6. 47.100 /  6. 47.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  1.100 /  4.  1.100
  libswresample   2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x36b3a80] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'twitter-files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 415 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 284 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
[mp4 @ 0x36b7dc0] Using AVStream.codec to pass codec parameters to muxers is deprecated, use AVStream.codecpar instead.
    Last message repeated 1 times
Output #0, mp4, to 'twitter-tmp.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.41.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 284 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3733160] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3733140] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x36b7dc0] Packet with invalid duration -512 in stream 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x3733140] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 2 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x36ba960] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x36b7dc0] Packet with invalid duration -512 in stream 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x36ba960] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 4 times
[mp4 @ 0x36b7dc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 306957, current: 306445; changing to 306958. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x36b7dc0] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 306958, current: 306957; changing to 306959. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x36ba960] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 1 times
frame=  750 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1088kB time=00:00:30.04 bitrate= 296.6kbits/s speed= 366x
```

OSX output:

```
ffmpeg version 3.0 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.31)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.0 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-opencl --enable-libx264 --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libxvid --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-vda
  libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
  libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
  libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
  libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
  libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
  libavresample   3.  0.  0 /  3.  0.  0
  libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
  libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49808c00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
Input #0, concat, from 'twitter-files.txt':
  Duration: N/A, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 415 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720, 284 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Output #0, mp4, to 'tmp-twitter.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf57.25.100
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 ([33][0][0][0] / 0x0021), yuv420p, 1280x720, q=2-31, 284 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 12800 tbc
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) ([64][0][0][0] / 0x0040), 48000 Hz, stereo, 130 kb/s
    Metadata:
      handler_name    : SoundHandler
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
  Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a005400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x7f9c4a000c00] Packet with invalid duration -512 in stream 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
    Last message repeated 1 times
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x7f9c4a000c00] Packet with invalid duration -512 in stream 1
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a005400] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c4a800e00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mp4 @ 0x7f9c4a000c00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 306957, current: 306445; changing to 306958. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mp4 @ 0x7f9c4a000c00] Non-monotonous DTS in output stream 0:0; previous: 306958, current: 306957; changing to 306959. This may result in incorrect timestamps in the output file.
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49800000] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 0x7f9c49010e00] Auto-inserting h264_mp4toannexb bitstream filter
frame=  750 fps=0.0 q=-1.0 Lsize=    1146kB time=00:00:30.04 bitrate= 312.4kbits/s speed= 192x
```

Comment: Are they all the same formats, number of streams, time base, etc?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Yes; I split them from an original file and am attempting to rejoin them.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include the output. Each file is playable, as well as joined files when joined in groups of two.

Comment: Reran the command, interesting to note the join worked correctly on my OSX ffmpeg (version 3.0), but failed on my ubuntu machine (output in the latest edit)

Comment: The command and complete console output from the OS X machine could be informative.

Comment: Added. Do you think it has to do with timestamps?

Comment: @LordNeckbeard Another interesting point is the segment, after `diff`'ing the ffprobe json outputs of each segment, the `start_time` and `start_pts` seem to be incrementing each segment, but not constantly (i.e. start_pts values are 0, 240, 480 and 768 for segment 1, 2,3 and 4).